# C# POST API Mercado Pago con codigo QR

Tags: c#, api, .net, mercadopago

necesito ayuda, estoy intentando enviar un Header al contenido de una peticion POST
a mercado pago para utilizar el codigo QR en c#,pero tengo un problema que dice como que estoy introduciendo el header donde "no va" y me tira el siguiente error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Misused header name, 'Authorization'. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, 
response headers with HttpResponseMessage, 
and content headers with HttpContent
```

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
     string Url = $"https://api.mercadopago.com/mpmobile/instore/qr/47986885/CAJA0001";
            var Client = new HttpClient();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                     new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "MI_ACCESS_TOKEN");

            CapaNegocios.Pagos.MPCheckout oTransaccion = new CapaNegocios.Pagos.MPCheckout()
            {
                sku_number = "12345",
                category = "Categoria1",
                title = "TiruloPrueba",
                description = "DescripcionPrueba",
                unit_price = 22,
                quantity = 1,
                unit_measure = "No se que es",
                total_amount = 22
            };
            var requestt = @"{{
'external_reference': '12345',
'title': 'Product order','notification_url': 'www.yourserver.com','total_amount': 100,'items': [{'sku_number': 'KS9999',
                        'category': 'UTILIDAD',
                        'title': 'Lapicera',
                        'description':'lapicera verde',
                        'unit_price': 100,
                        'quantity': 8,
                        'unit_measure': 'unit',
                        'total_amount': 800
                      }
                    ],
                    'taxes': [
                      {
                                  'value': 19,
                        'type': 'IVA'
                      }
                    ],
                    'sponsor': {
                                  'id': 446566691
                    },
                    'cash_out': { }
               }
            }";

            requestt = requestt.Trim();
            var Datas = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestt);
            var Data = JsonSerializer.Serialize<CapaNegocios.Pagos.MPCheckout>(oTransaccion);
   
            HttpContent contenido = new StringContent(Datas, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
             contenido.Headers.Add("Authorization", "MI_ACCESS_TOKEN"); // ACA NECESITO METER EL HEADER!!!!

            var httpResponse = await Client.PostAsync(Url, contenido);



            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var Resultado =await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
```

Como bien dije y especifique en el codigo, necesito meter el HEADER por lo que estoy viendo en el HttpContent(contenido),
alguno sabe como solucionar esto?
Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Uhmm... El error es claro. Aquí está la documentación para [RequestHeaders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders?view=net-6.0), [ResponseHeaders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpresponseheaders?view=net-6.0) y [ContentHeaders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders?view=net-6.0). `Authorization` sólo está en los `RequestHeader`. Cuando haces `contenido.Headers.Add()`, `contenido` es de tipo `ContentHeader`. Ya lo tienes en el `DefaultRequestHeader`

Comment: Hola @Arriel gracias por responder, entiendo pero mira lo que dice luego:

Ya saque el Authorization desde el ContentHeader, para que no tire ese error, pero me tira un Bad Request (error 400), y no se porque...
Me aparece que los headers que envio son estos:

Comment: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request':

 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
  Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
  Timing-Allow-Origin: *
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8